# Template Builder fails with incorrect content type error after network changes

Tags: 2009

Some changes were made in the network at the client, and now we are getting the following error. It seems that this is a rights issue, but what can we do to solve this?

```
Client found response content type of 'text/html', but expected 'text/xml'.
The request failed with the error message:
--
The page cannot be displayed because an internal server error has occurred.
--.
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.ReadResponse(SoapClientMessage message, WebResponse response, Stream responseStream, Boolean asyncCall)
   at System.Web.Services.Protocols.SoapHttpClientProtocol.Invoke(String methodName, Object[] parameters)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.CompoundTemplates.DomainModel.Proxy.CompoundTemplateWebService.Login(Boolean initData)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.Templating.CompoundTemplates.DomainModel.Model.Login(Uri contentManager, NetworkCredential credentials)
   at Tridion.ContentManager.UI.CompoundTemplateDesigner.DesignerForm.LogonAs(Uri uri, Exception initialError)
```

UPDATE:
Thanks for the reply's it seems related to webdav. webdav is returning a 500 error.

Webdav in iss connection test:
The server is configured to use pass-through authentication with a built-in account to access the specified physical path. However, IIS Manager cannot verify whether the built-in account has access. Make sure that the application pool identity has Read access to the physical path. If this server is joined to a domain, and the application pool identity is NetworkService or LocalSystem, verify that \$ has Read access to the physical path. Then test these settings again.

Comment: Can you find out what changes were made and where exactly (on the CMS server or elsewhere in the network)? Also why are you thinking this is a rights issue?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Template Builder uses an standard web service to connect to the CMS so that it expect an XML response, in this case it seems that you are receiving a HTML response so it could be for a few reasons.

- Are you using SSO?, if that is the case, ensure that your SSO software is not protecting the Templating Web Service and that your Web service is configured to use Windows/Basic authentication and not Forms Authentication.
- Checks that you can access to the templating web service and that you are not receiving a HTML page as a response.

I hope this helps.

Comment: This happens often when the web service returns an error, which is formatted as HTML.

Comment: Exactly: so the easiest way to trouble shoot is what Eric suggest in his second bullet point. Connect to the same URL with a browser and read the HTML. Usually this will give you a good idea what is going wrong, and definitely more useful than the "I expected XML, you gave me HTML" whining of Template Builder.